# Incorrect document root being set up

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have set up two virtual hosts. The configuration file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerName a.b.com
                ServerAlias https://a.b.com a.b.com https://www.a.b.com
                ServerAdmin admin@veneratech.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /usr/local/ssl/crt/veneratech.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/veneratech.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>

       <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerName api.b.com
                ServerAlias https://api.b.com api.b.com https://www.api.b.com
                ServerAdmin admin@veneratech.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apibroker/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /usr/local/ssl/crt/veneratech.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/veneratech.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

     </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

When the user opens `api.b.com`, I want the index file under `/var/www/html/apibroker/` to trigger. But it never reaches `/var/www/html/apibroker/` but ends up directly inside `/var/www/html/`. What could be the reason for this?

I edited the file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` and then copied this to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Also, how could this be achieved by `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Virtual Host blocks to:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
```

Also, you probably should set up two completely separate document roots, something like this:

For `a.b.com`, use

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/main_site/
```

For `api.b.com`, use

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/api_site/
```